# How to set date format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm" in linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

This is my code:

```
var qry = (from u in _db.ApplicationUsers
           select new UserBroadcastDTO() 
           {
               UserId = u.Id,
               DateCreated = u.DateCreated
           }).OrderByDescending(q => q.DateCreated);
```

I have this exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can I convert date format in linq?

Comment: Return a `DateTime` and let the presentation layer handle formatting.

Comment: And when you format, don't use `hh` without an AM/PM designator... use `HH` for 24 hours.

Comment: I'd also suggest using `h` instead of `hh` so you don't get a padded zero with hours 1-9 but that is just my preference.

Comment: ToString does not work the way you think it does.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that formatting doesn't belong in the Linq query itself. The query is concerned with data, not presentation.

Now, if you are trying to *project* the results of the query into something for display, then make sure you enumerate the collection *before* doing your formatting. You can call .ToList(), but in most cases, simply adding an .AsEnumerable() will do the trick, drawing a line in the sand between what *can* be made part of the SQL (or other back-end store) query, and what can't. Then, you add another select to do your projection.

Like this:

```
var qry = _db.ApplicationUsers
    .OrderByDescending(q => q.DateCreated)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select new UserBroadcastDTO
       {
           UserId = u.Id,
           DateCreated = u.DateCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
       });
```

The .AsEnumerable call can be a .ToList if you want, but .AsEnumerable will work just fine and still defers execution until later if needed, but the important thing is that you're *stopping* it from being an IQueryable, so anything after that point doesn't try to work its way into the SQL query, and you won't get the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because LINQ to Entities is trying to convert the expression tree into SQL query and `.ToString(string)` can not be translated into SQL. you should handle the result in your presentation layer for example inside your view in an MVC app:

```
@Model.DateCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

ypu need to materialize the query so that can happen in linq to objects linq to entities cannot do that

```
var qry = _db.ApplicationUsers.OrderByDescending(q => q.DateCreated)
                              .Select(u => new UserBroadcastDTO {
                                    UserId = u.Id,
                                    DateCreated = u.DateCreated                                   
                              });

// do your additional logic then materialize the query   
var formattedresults = qry.ToList().Select(q => new UserBroadcastDTO {
    UserId = q.Id,
    DateCreated = q.DateCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
});
```